# How to make vector arrows?

Tags: vector, rstudio

I would like to make a vector over my beta symbol.
What I use for the moment is:

```
$A\overrightarrow{\beta}$
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$A\vv{\beta}$
$A\vec{\beta}$
```

Note that all of these works if I add another symbol next to `\beta`.
I have been googeling but these are all the solutions I found.

Edit: So to clarify.
I use R Markdown in R-studio, which uses latex (maybe this is the problem).
From the code `$A\vec{\beta}=\vec{b}$` I get the output shown on this picture.

[image: Picture of my output]

However, I want it to be:

[image: The output I want]

The "solutions" I have stated above works if I add another symbol next to the beta, like this:

```
$A\vec{\beta A}=\vec{b}$
```

I get this output:

[image]

However, I do not want that extra A at the end.

Edit 2: **SOLVED:**

The problem seem to be that this issue only appears when you hover your mouse over the equation. When you actually compile the entire thing it seems to work fine.
Since I had a lot of data in my rmd file I did not want to compile it but tried it in a new empty rmd file and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't add any symbol next to `\beta`, i.e. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\overrightarrow{\beta}$\end{document}` and it is Ok. What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Could you clarify the question.  You say all of the above work, so what problem are you trying to solve.  Incidentally it is better to post a minimal document demonstrating code, including the necessary packages, rather than code snippets.

Comment: It works for me. Did you compile the code in some special way which led to problems before "googeling"?

Comment: Updated with solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
    $a\overrightarrow{\beta}b$
    $a\vec{\beta}b$
    $a\vv{\beta}b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem was that R markdown did not show the arrow when I hovered my mouse over it but only when I compiled it.